# Is it correct to use "include" in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> 1. Over time we have extended the collection to ***include*** shoes and bags."
> 2. Over time we have extended the collection to shoes and bags."

> 3. Over time we have extended the collection to ***include*** orange, mint and apple flavor."
> 4. Over time we have extended the collection to orange, mint and apple flavor"

Do the above sentences convey similar meaning with and without the word *include*?

As an elementary learner, I'm leaning towards #1 and #4 but I can't explain why grammatically.

Comment: What do you mean you're leaning towards #1 and #4? Are you asking if they're correct grammar or if they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not convey the same meaning.

> Over time we have extended the collection to **include** orange, mint and apple flavor.

This means the collection did not initially include any of orange, mint or apple flavours, but now it does.

> Over time we have extended the collection to orange, mint and apple flavor

This means "orange, mint and apple flavour" is the full collection, but initially, it only had one or two of them.